# Video Banner Errors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a site with a banner video that worked fine when we were running jquery2.  After upgrading to jquery 3, the banner video no longer works. Can anyone look at the code and see what is wrong? When I look at the console in chrome, I see this error (as well as a cookie error) : jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: e.indexOf is not a function
at S.fn.init.S.fn.load (jquery.min.js:2)
at (index):532

```
  <video id="BannerVideo" class="Banner" muted playsinline loop oncanplaythrough="playBannerVideo()"></video>
<script>
function playBannerVideo()
{
  var videoElement = document.getElementById('BannerVideo');
  try 
  {
    videoElement.play();
  }
  catch(err) {}
}

var basePosterURL = '/FCC/media/Images/Home2018/Banner/Banner.jpg';
var baseVideoURL = '/FCC/media/Images/Home2018/Banner/BannerVideo.mp4';

function getNameForCurrentWidth()
{
  var bodyWidth = document.body.clientWidth; // $('body').width();
  if (bodyWidth <= 767)
    return '_Phone';
  
  if (bodyWidth <= 990)
    return '_Tablet';
  
  return ''; // Desktop
}

var loadedWidthName;
function loadBannerVideo(posterOnly)
{
  var newWidthName = getNameForCurrentWidth();
  if(newWidthName == loadedWidthName)
    return;

  loadedWidthName = newWidthName;
  var videoElement = document.getElementById('BannerVideo');
   
  if (!videoElement.paused)
    videoElement.pause();
  
  videoElement.src = '';
  videoElement.poster = addToFilename(basePosterURL, loadedWidthName);
  
  if (posterOnly == true)
    return;
  
  setBannerVideoSrc(loadedWidthName);
}

function setBannerVideoSrc(newWidthName)
{
  // don't play video if in design or edit modes
  if( $('body.DesignMode').length == 1 ||  $('body.EditMode').length == 1)
    return;
  
  var videoElement = document.getElementById('BannerVideo');
  videoElement.src = addToFilename(baseVideoURL, newWidthName);
  videoElement.load();
}

// load poster as soon as possible
$(function() // document.ready
{
  loadBannerVideo(true);
});

  // load and play video after everything else loads
$(window).load(function()
{
  setBannerVideoSrc(loadedWidthName);
});

var resizeTimeout;
$(window).resize(function()
{ 
  clearTimeout(resizeTimeout);
  resizeTimeout = setTimeout(resizeEnd, 200);   
});
function resizeEnd()
{
  loadBannerVideo();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article with the same error](http://www.studyzone4u.com/post-details/uncaught-typeerror-eindexof-is-not-a-function-in-jquery), the `load()`, `error()` and `toggle()` event listeners are deprecated. Meaning you're using out of date code that isn't supported by jQuery no more.

Analyzing your code I see that you use the `load()` event listener. The fix here would be to use the [`on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) to listen to the `load` event.

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
  // ...
});
```

But your code uses so little jQuery and way more *vanilla* JavaScript that it makes little sense to use jQuery at all. I'd recommend that you ditch it if you don't use it anywhere else. In case you do, the snippet below is the equivalent of what you posted, but without jQuery.

```
function playBannerVideo() {
  var videoElement = document.getElementById("BannerVideo");
  try {
    videoElement.play();
  } catch (err) {}
}

var basePosterURL = "/FCC/media/Images/Home2018/Banner/Banner.jpg";
var baseVideoURL = "/FCC/media/Images/Home2018/Banner/BannerVideo.mp4";

function getNameForCurrentWidth() {
  var bodyWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
  if (bodyWidth <= 767) return "_Phone";
  if (bodyWidth <= 990) return "_Tablet";

  return ""; // Desktop
}

var loadedWidthName;
function loadBannerVideo(posterOnly) {
  var newWidthName = getNameForCurrentWidth();
  if (newWidthName == loadedWidthName) return;

  loadedWidthName = newWidthName;
  var videoElement = document.getElementById("BannerVideo");

  if (!videoElement.paused) videoElement.pause();

  videoElement.src = "";
  videoElement.poster = addToFilename(basePosterURL, loadedWidthName);

  if (posterOnly == true) return;

  setBannerVideoSrc(loadedWidthName);
}

function setBannerVideoSrc(newWidthName) {
  // don't play video if in design or edit modes
  if (document.querySelector("body.DesignMode").length == 1 || document.querySelector("body.EditMode").length == 1)
    return;

  var videoElement = document.getElementById("BannerVideo");
  videoElement.src = addToFilename(baseVideoURL, newWidthName);
  videoElement.load();
}

// load poster as soon as possible
loadBannerVideo(true);

// load and play video after everything else loads
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    setBannerVideoSrc(loadedWidthName);
});

var resizeTimeout;
window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
  clearTimeout(resizeTimeout);
  resizeTimeout = setTimeout(resizeEnd, 200);
});

function resizeEnd() {
  loadBannerVideo();
}
```

Comment: If I want to add a vtt file to the above script, how would I do it?  Just adding the track code within the video code doesnt work.

Comment: If it helped you, then please be sure to [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so that future users with the same question will know what to do. As for your second question, please create a new question so we can help you out.